# It appears that my ajax works but nothing is being posted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post the value of my selector to a php file but it isnt working. My success function works and when i go to "your_php_script.php" the page works and the php runs as expected. Why wont the php page show up on the page with the ajax? I edited my post to add the database connection function from database_connection.php

```
// html & jquery
 <select name="rooftop" id="rooftop" class="selectMenu">
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>


    <button id="barButton">click</button>

    <div id="showBars">

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

                          $("#barButton").click(function() {
                            var selected = $("#rooftop").val();
                            $.ajax({
                                   type: "POST",
                                   url: "your_php_script.php",
                                   data: {selected: selected},
                                   success: function(){
                                   alert("works");
                                   }

                            });
                          });

// code on your_php_script.php
<?php

require_once("database_connection.php");
$db = db_connect();

 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('works1'); </script>";
    $selected = $_POST["selected"];
    if(isset($selected)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('works2'); </script>";
        $sql = "SELECT bar_name, area, hourStart, hourEnd FROM barInfo WHERE rooftop = 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "<table id='list'><tr><th><h3>Name</h3></th><th><h3> Area</h3></th><th><h3>Happy Hour Times</h3></th></tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<tr> <th> <h6> " . $row["bar_name"] . "</h6> </th> <th> <h6>" . $row["area"] . "</h6> </th> <th> <h6>" . $row["hourStart"] . "-" . $row["hourEnd"] . "</h6> </th> </tr>";
            }
            echo "</table";
        }

    }
db_disconnect($db);

?>


// database connection
function db_connect() {
        global $connection, $servername, $username, $password, $database;
        $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database) or die("Unable to Connect");
        return $connection;
    }
```

Comment: how did you confirm that ajax is not submitting data? I think it must do, no error in this part. Be ensure `var selected = $("#rooftop").val();` have some value there.

Comment: `if(isset($selectd))` - Where do you define `$selectd` (also, is it a typo)?

Comment: `if(isset($selectd))` is it correct ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$selected` ?

Comment: Also, as @Magnus said, where is `$selectd` defined if its correct ?

Comment: I previously alerted $("#rooftop").val(); so i know that it works

Comment: have u checked in network tab in chrome console 
?

Comment: i updated the typo and it still doesnt work. the $selected variable is supposed to be from the ajax post. The initial alert doesnt work either so i dont think it connects to the php page in the first place.

Comment: Don't you need to take the value of $selected from POST like : `$selected = $_POST['selected']` and then use `if(isset($selected))`

Comment: Firstly try a simple `echo ("something"); die;` in your_php_script.php at the very beginning and check in network that if it even reaches this file after ajax request

Comment: under the response tab in the xhr network tag it shows the first alert, but why isnt the alert actually working?

Comment: You mean to say it prints there "work1" in the xhr network console but the alert is not being popped ?

Comment: @JitendraAhuja ya that is what happens

Comment: Still you have not changed your variable in if condition. Please make it `if(isset($selected))`

Comment: i updated the $select varaible and now everything shows up in the console but not on the page

Comment: In the code here, i can still see this `if(isset($selectd))` . Why ? Please change the spelling of selected by using `if(isset($selected))`

Comment: Also , is this all that you have in this file ? I mean where is the $connection variable defined ? Have you included any other php file from which $connection can be used ?

Comment: i updated it on here too but nothing is still showing up on the page even though it does show up in the console

Comment: @JitendraAhuja i updated to show all of the code i have on the php page

Comment: Ok now try `echo mysqli_num_rows($result)`, is it actually greater than 0 , to enter this condition `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)`

Comment: it says its null in the console

Comment: That does means either $connection is not properly defined OR there is no such entry in database where `barInfo` = 1 so its returning back nothing

Comment: Can you post your database_connection.php file code here ? So we can check if there is even a connection to the db, done correctly or not

Comment: i created the database in the terminal and i ran the sql in the terminal and it works

Comment: It might be the case that $connection is not actually connecting. Do u have this in ur `database_connection.php`  file ? `if ($connection->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);  
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that the number of rows in result is not more than 0, That does means either $connection is not properly defined OR there is no such entry in database where `barInfo = 1` so its returning back nothing.

So firstly you should check your `database_connection.php` file if the connection to the DB is done properly or not, because it could be the case that this file (`your_php_script.php`) is not getting `$connection` from `database_connection.php` file.

Also, as i mentioned earlier, dataType is important (not mandatory though). Even more important is to append the incoming data in the apt. element, for which your success function should look like :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html"
    url: "your_php_script.php",
    data: {
        selected: selected
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert("works");
        jQuery("#showBars").html(result); 
    },
    error: function(error) {
       alert(error);
    }
});
```

Things to remember while using ajax:

1) Make sure the `dataType` attribute is appropriately defined.  If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.

2) `Success` function should be defined properly with the proper usage of the incoming data, on how to use it in your HTML view.

3) Make habit of using `error` function as it will help you get your errors when it not enters `Success` function and have any error(s).

Comment: Please Accept the Answer and Do tell which trick worked for you

Comment: adding datatype and jQuery("#showBars").html(result); 
    }, to my success function made it work. I updated my post to show where connection is defined, im not sure why it is affecting the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

First you since you are using echo in your php response you must define that there will be a response in your Ajax request.

So your Ajax will be replaced by something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text"
    url: "your_php_script.php",
    data: {
        selected: selected
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("works");
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, you can go for : `dataType : 'html'`